# Problem generating random string in Azure Cloud Shell Bash

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I am trying to generate a random string of a certain length in Bash. This works in every other Bash shell I could test (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Debian 10)

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
n8a4wxvb01
$
```

`cat /dev/urandom` – endless stream of bytes

`tr -dc ‘a-z0-9’` – only return lowercase characters and digits

`fold -w 10` – break at 10 characters

`head -n 1` – return the first line of the stream

In the Azure Cloud Shell Bash, this hangs. It returns the random string but never exits. The call to `head -n 1` never exits after printing the value.

I have a work around but it seems backwards

```
head -n 10 /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
```

Comment: What do you mean on "The call to head -n 1 never exits after printing the value."?

Comment: If you run that command on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, you get a single value value and the command completes. If you try this in Azure Cloud Shell Bash, you will see the command return a value but then hang. You can get it only exits with ctrl-c.

I made this example easy enough so that anyone can cut and paste this and try it.

Comment: If there is any doubt that it is the call to `head -n 1`, just remove it from the end of the statement and you will see an endless stream of 10 character random values

Answer (score 0):

The command works fine both in personal Linux OS and the Azure Cloud Shell Bash.

Azure Cloud Shell Bash:

[image]

Personal Linux OS:

[image]

I don't think there would be a difference between them. The Azure Cloud Shell is just a VM running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Take a look at [the features of the Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features).

**Update:**

You can take a look at the [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192203/how-to-use-dev-urandom), the answers probably show the reasons that the command does not work in Azure Cloud Shell. And as I know it is not a high performing system. Otherwise, use `cat` is not a good idea to get a random string. I suggest the `head`.

Comment: Yes. my work around works fine, but my original code does not. The first code snippet is idiomatically correct Bash and should work everywhere. 

`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1` does not work

Comment: @JamesP See the updates, I think it's the possible reason.

Comment: @JamesP Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `openssl` for creating random strings (as hex or base64):

```
openssl rand -hex 10

openssl rand -base64 10
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-rand.html